# How do I detect Sony Bravia internet browser?

Tags: browser, television, sony

I'd like to write detector of Sony Bravia TV internet browser. I knew it's Opera browser but I don't know exactly what's properties to detect it ? Anyone know what's Opera version or how can I know it's Sony TV browser ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detection method depends on whenever you're doing it on a server side (in which case you have to look at the extra headers that browser in tv send) or on a client side javascript, in which case you have to look at the `navigator.userAgent` property.

As to extra headers, the only information I could find is this example headers:

```
X-AV-Physical-Unit-Info: pa="BRAVIA KDL-46XBR9";,X-AV-Client-Info: av=5.0; cn="Sony Corporation"; mn="BRAVIA KDL-46XBR9"; mv="1.7";
```

As you can see above, tv identifies itself with extra X-AV-Physical-Unit-Info and X-AV-Client-info headers

As to client-side detection of tv browser, I found [this post](http://www.georgepaterson.com/2010/11/04/google-tv-user-agent-strings/) (refering to google tv but still...) in which you can see the content of a navigator.userAgent property on two devices, including Sony Bravia.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.127 Large Screen Safari/533.4 GoogleTV/ 162671
```